# Resize an image with a max width and height, using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

**Given an input image `test.png`, how to resize it (downsizing) such that it fits in a 400x500 pixels box, keeping aspect ratio?**

Is it possible directly with `cv2.resize`, or do we have to compute the sizing factor manually?

Comment: manually. You can use some utility library such as https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#resizing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no helper function for this already built-in in `cv2`. Here is a working solution:

```
maxwidth, maxheight = 400, 500

import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test2.png')
f1 = maxwidth / img.shape[1]
f2 = maxheight / img.shape[0]
f = min(f1, f2)  # resizing factor
dim = (int(img.shape[1] * f), int(img.shape[0] * f))
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', resized)
```